# Link to Category Index in Rich Text Field

Tags: categories, redactor, richtext

I have a Category group set up with URLs enabled. I'm just wondering if it's possible to link to a Category Index from the Link feature within a Rich Text Field. I realize I can manually create my own link (i.e. /path/to/category) via "Insert Link"  but was looking for a dynamic link along the lines of the "Link to Entry" or "Link to an Asset" methods.

*Craft 2.4 Support added!*

http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/8126490-add-a-link-to-a-category-option-to-rich-text-fie

Comment: +1, 'Link to a category' would definitely be a great addition to Craft. I don't believe this is possible in core Craft at the moment Mat, so unless someone has built a plugin for this it might be worth sending a feature request to P&T: support@pixelandtonic.com

Comment: Voted to close this question, as only P&T can add features to the Rich Text Field. Good feature request though.

Comment: Gotta agree with these guys. At the very least, this is simply an idea for a plugin... at the most, it's a feature request. Feel free to contact P&T directly with your feature request!

Comment: Thanks all, appreciate the replies. I will send a request P&T.

Comment: In case anyone else is interested - I just realized the Category Sources plugin adds this feature to the redactor link button.